# Animate New View from Tab Bar Application Template XCode

Tags: iphone, xcode, view, switching, uitabview

I have created a new Tab Bar Application template in xcode. How should I properly setup a new view that animates in (Slide Up) when a button is pressed? I've seen this done using the NavigationController.

I've added a navigation bar and a button with an action that adds a sub view using this code:

```
(IBAction)newPost:(id)sender
{
    // Load UIViewController from nib
    PostViewController *screen = [[PostViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"PostViewController" bundle:nil];

    // Add to UINavigationController's stack, i.e. the view for this UITabBarController view
    [self.view addSubview:screen.view];

    // Release music, no longer needed since it is retained by the navController
    [screen release];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you're asking, but if you just want a new view controller to present itself modally upward just do this.

1.) New File --> View Controller

2.)

```
newViewcontroller *viewController = [[newViewcontroller alloc] initWithNibName:@"newViewcontroller" bundle:nil];
[self presentModalViewController:viewController animated:YES];
[viewController release];
```